# Can a national annual data report be reworked as an annual journal?

Tags: publications, journals, publishability

I have some questions regarding developing an academic journal. We produce a comprehensive annual scientific data report once a year. We are looking for a way of making our report data more accessible through online bibliographic services. We are exploring the possibility of developing our annual report as a journal published by us and containing articles that contain the data findings of the annual report. Our annual report is already peer reviewed and the articles are written by different authors, so we see we can at least fulfil Pubmed’s journal criteria if we were to adapt it into a journal. However, we do not want to open the journal to external manuscript contributions as this would stretch us beyond capacity! Basically, we want to produce an annual journal containing articles on the annual report only. So, I was wondering if anyone could tell me if this would constitute a journal? And if you know of any journals that have developed from an annual report and are dedicated to only producing journal articles based on this content? Any advice, guidance and/or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The fairly prestigious 'Annual Review of ...' series (eg AR of Sociology, AR of Physics) is entirely invited articles and internal reviewers. So it's clearly not a requirement that the journal be open to unsolicited articles for it to be considered a journal.